# How to search in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the three models:

```
class Joinedtravel < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :travel
    belongs_to :user   
end

class Travel < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :joinedtravels
    belongs_to :user
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :joinedtravels
    has_many :travels
end
```

How can I obtain all travels that a user has joined in the past? 
I did something like that:

```
@user = User.find(id)
@past_travels = Travel.where('travels.data < ?', DateTime.now)
@all_joinedtravels = @user.joinedtravels.travels
```

but i don't kwon how to correctly join the results.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to fix the relationship

```rb
class Joinedtravel < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :travel
  belongs_to :user   
end

class Travel < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users, through: joinedtravels
  has_many :joinedtravels
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :travels, through: joinedtravels
  has_many :joinedtravels
end
```

Then you can simply search it using

```rb
User
  .find(id)
  .travels
  .where('travels.data < ?', DateTime.now)
```

Comment: In this way I will find all the travels that belongs to the user. But in this application a user can create a travel and can join a travel that someone created. My goal is to find just the travels the user joined and not the ones he created.

Comment: Perhaps the user class should be `has_many :joinedtravels` and `has_many :travels, through: joinedtravels` ? Two times `has_many :travels` seems like a typo :)

Comment: Seems weird also to me. Do you know how can I write the query?
Basically I want to find all joinedtravels where: 
-the date that the joinedtravel belongs to is lower than DateTime.now
-the user_id that the joinedtravel belongs to is equal to @user_id

Comment: @donald I think Amit's answer is exactly what you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
@user = User.find(id)
@past_joinedtravels = @user.joinedtravels.joins(:travels).where('travels.date < ?', DateTime.now)
```

Try this in the console, and pay attention to the sql produced. That will show you possible errors.

The `travels`in the joins clause is the model name. The `travels`in the where clause must be the literal database table name, which I just guessed.

Answer (score -1):

Seems to me you'd be better off using a has_and_belongs_to_many relations and a join table to join the User and Travel models as long as you're not including any additional information in the JoinedTravel model?

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association

```
class Travel < ApplicationRecord
   has_and_belongs_to_many :user
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
   has_and_belongs_to_many :travels
end


@user = User.find(id)
@past_travels = Travel.where('travels.data < ?', DateTime.now)
@user_travels = @user.travels
```

You could then see if a user has any travels:

```
@user.travels.present?
```

Comment: Yes, i'm including other additional information in the JoinedTravel model. I was trying to do something like this, but doesn't work: 
@all_joinedtravels =@user.joinedtravels.where(Joinedtravel.travel.data < DateTime.now)

Basically i want to find just the travels there the user joined in the past and not all the travels (which can be for example the travels that the user created)